# Gparted - Can't resize win 10 partition?

Tags: partitioning, gparted

I can't to be able to re-size windows 10 file system partition using `Gparted`.

The partition is un-mounted and this is not about swap-partitioning

[image: Gparted Partition]

Do help me?

Comment: Post a link to gparted screenshot.

Comment: http://s7.postimg.org/vrbgh42vv/Screenshot_from_2015_08_23_12_56_10.png

Comment: And what are you trying to do with sda7? You can only shrink it. And there is no Windows partition. It is called "Windows" but it is `ext4`.

Comment: sda7, as you can see in the picture has a label of windows 10 new, that's why i'm trying to extend it

Comment: also, theres sda3, but i can't extend that one either

Comment: You can extend a partition if there is unallocated space beside of it.

Comment: @MartinThornton It is not the case. It is GPT and swap is not related.

Comment: Sorry, you're right @Pilot6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not just extend any partition you like. There must be some space at least at one side of the partition. If that is not the case, you need to move other partitions to get this space in the right place.

**Important note:** If you move the left side of linux or Windows boot partition, the system will not boot. You will need to re-install grub.

Comment: and well, how do i move them?

Comment: Just move them one by one. sda5, sda7, etc.